# Стоит ли создавать новый класс для вариации алгоритма?

Tags: java, алгоритм, классы, условия

Есть класс `А`, который реализует некий алгоритм.
На главной форме есть чекбокс, при отметке которого алгоритм выполняется с небольшими изменениями в логике.
Также могут появиться еще много чекбоксов, которые по-немногу меняют логику алгоритма.
Получается, для обработки всех чекбоксов в алгоритме класса `А` надо будет писать много условий, код усложняется как визуально, так и для понимания.

Или лучше создавать новые классы `А2`, `А3` и т.д., которые "в чистом виде" будут реализовывать свои вариации алгоритма?

Comment: Шаблон [стратегия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стратегия_(шаблон_проектирования)) подойдет? Вкратце, там будет создаваться по классу на каждую реализацию алгоритма. Каждый класс, в свою очередь, будет наследоваться от интерфейса. Таким образом, Вы сможете менять реализацию алгоритма на лету и выбирать нужную, в зависимости от нажатого чекбокса.

Comment: Я думаю, здесь однозначно верного ответа быть не может. Наверное, в большинстве случаев подойдет множество классов, с одним алгоритмом каждый, но в каких-то ситуациях удобней будет один класс с разыми методами для разных алгоритмов или алгоритмы с вариантами, зависящими от параметров, или комбинация того, другого и третьего. Никогда не надо применять шаблоны слепо, всегда надо оценивать конкретную ситуацию.

Comment: @StasDorozhko, вообще-то, шаблон "стратегия" - это немножко не об этом. Он применяется, когда выбор конкретного алгоритма зависит не от пользователя, а от других обстоятельств, о которых пользоватль может ничего не знать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд лучше создать новый класс под каждый алгоритм.

Т.е. вы создаете интерфейс допустим такой:

```
interface AlgoritmExecutor{
     execute();
}
```

И для каждого класса алгоритмов его реализуете, и сам алгоритм пишите в нем. В этом случае при добавлении нового алгоритма Вам надо будет написать новый класс, а не лезть в старый, добавляя новые условия.

Но остается вопрос как выбирать нужный класс. Тут моё предложение не лучшее. Создать фабрику, которая будет принимать пачку `boolean` за каждый чекбокс.

```
class AlgoritmFactory{
    static AlgoritmExecutor chooseAlgoritm(boolean... checkbox){
        //тут исходя из включенных чекбоксов выбираете нужный класс алгоритма 
    }
}
```

---

Это удобно тем, что в слое вида вы обращаетесь к фабрике, передаете ей все чекбоксы и получаете выбранный алгоритм в виде интерфейса.

```
public void algoritmAction(){
     AlgoritmExecutor  algoritm = AlgoritmFactory(checkbox1.isEnabled(), checkbox2.isEnabled(), checkbox3.isEnabled());
     algoritm.execute();
}
```

но фабрика становится не очень понятна для стороннего читателя из-за пачки булевых значений.